# Is it ok to query inside a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in one database. I am querying the first table limit by 10 then loop the results. And inside the while loop, I am doing again another query using a data from the first query as a parameter. Here is an example of the script:

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect(host,username,password);
    mysql_select_db(game_server);

    //My first query
    $q1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM game_characters ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10');

    while($character = mysql_fetch_object($q1)){
    //My second query
        $q2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM game_board WHERE id="'.$character->id.'"');
        $player = mysql_fetch_object($q2);
    }
?>
```

So if I have a result of 100 rows, then the second query will execute 100 times. And I know it is not good. How can I make it better. Is there a way to do everything in one query? What if there is another query inside the while loop where a data from the second query as a parameter is used?

> P.S.: I am doing a rankings system for an online game.

Comment: It is a possibility, but I recommand JOIN http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: Yes it is OK. It's also OK to wear sandals in the snow. In fact you should not do that as it performs very slow. Try to combine your two queries into one using a `JOIN`.

Comment: I also recommend you to use prepared statements - in case `$character->id` is somehow corrupted and it could lead to SQL injection...

Comment: @knightrider Why does that matter?

Comment: But if I have thousand of rows to loop, then it will query a thousand times too. Will that lag/hang the server or something?

Comment: @feeela If yes, then find the range and execute a single query to get all the data in one call

Comment: inner join. much better.

Comment: @Jhon Andrew Yes it will slow down your PHP application and probably even the server, depending on your server settings and the amounts of data processed. You answer are already given. Please read the answers and comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in one query if you use JOINs.

```
SELECT * FROM game_board AS b 
    LEFT JOIN game_characters AS c ON b.id = c.id 
ORDER BY c.score DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

You can also use nested query

```
SELECT * FROM game_board AS b WHERE 
  id IN (SELECT id FROM game_characters AS c ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10)
```

You can also put all game_character.id into an array, and use

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM game_board AS b WHERE b.id IN (" . implode(', ', $game_character_ids) . ")";
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I will just do a nested query. I will try also using JOIN's. But which is much better, JOIN's or nested query?

Comment: `JOIN`, I think, but depends on a data set. If a game_board is a huge table (hundreds thousands of rows), I think it will be better to use nested select, otherwise use join. You can always call `EXPLAIN` and learn how to read its output: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `JOIN`?

This way there will be no queries within the `while` loop:

```
$con = mysql_connect(host,username,password);
mysql_select_db(game_server);

//My first query
$q1 = mysql_query('
    SELECT * 
    FROM game_characters gc 
    LEFT JOIN game_board gb ON gc.id = gb.id
    ORDER BY score DESC 
    LIMIT 10
');

while($character = mysql_fetch_object($q1)){
    // do Your stuff here, no other query...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach here would be to collect all the IDs in a concatenated string str in form 'id1', 'id2', 'id3', ... and use:
select * from game_board where id in (str)

Comment: Is an `IN (…)` search as efficient as a `JOIN`?

Comment: @feeela no, this answer is giving poor advice.  Making two trips to the database is never going to outperform a JOIN query.  Furthermore the syntax for writing a secure mysqli query with a variable number of placeholders and bound parameters will damage the readability of your script.

Answer (score -1):

What about if you do something like the following:

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect(host,username,password);
    mysql_select_db(game_server);

    //My first query
    $q1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM game_characters ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10');

    while($character = mysql_fetch_object($q1)){
    //My second query
        $characters .= " ' $character->id ' ,"
    }
    $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM game_board WHERE id in (substr($characters,0,strlen($characters - 2))");
    $player = mysql_fetch_object($q2);
?>
```