# can we simplify "while" inside of "while"?

Tags: php, sql

i need some little help ,,,

I have a data like this.., (I use php mysql)

Initially there was no problem with this, but as time goes by, my data is getting bigger and bigger.
finally its made my program slow ..
I think maybe because I used "while" inside of "while". make SQL is called multiple times.
is there a solution to make it faster ??

[image: non-original data]

I have hundreds of data in tb1 and thousands in tb2 T.T

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. See the meta post [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13703050/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using loops to iterate over tables.  SQL is an inherently set based declarative language.  So, you should just join the tables, order the result set, and then use a single loop with presentation logic.  Use this query:

```sql
SELECT tb1.id_a, tb2.id_b, tb2.data
FROM tb1
INNER JOIN tb2 ON tb2.id_a = tb1.id_a
```

Then, use this PHP script:

```php
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>No.</th><th>id_b</th><th>data</th></tr>";
$a = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($a == null || $row['id_a'] != $a) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id_a'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td colspan=2>data" . $row['id_a'];
        echo "</tr>";
        $a = $row['id_a'];
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id_b'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['data'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: ...and of course, no one should be using `mysql_` anymore.

Comment: There is probably a "duplicate" of this, but between the doubts in the query, and the presentation logic, it seemed worth answering to me `:-)`

Comment: I didn't say anything this time :)